# Angular 4 raise unhandled event to parent

Tags: angular, eventemitter

I have this structure inside of a main admin-tournament component

**admin-tournament.component.html:**

```
<fixture-league></fixture-league>
```

**fixture-league.component.html**

```
<md-tab-group>
  <md-tab *ngFor="let f of fixture" label="{{ f.date | date }}">
    <match *ngFor="let m of f" [match]="m"></match>
  </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

**match.component.html**

```
<team [team]="match.local_team" (click)="onLocalClick.emit()"></team>
<ul>
   <li (click)="onDateClick.emit()">{{ match.date | date:"HH:mm"}}</li>
   <li (click)="onResultClick.emit()">{{ match.result | myResultPipe }}</li>
<ul>
<team [team]="match.visitor_team" (click)="onVisitorClick.emit()"></team>
```

I want to handle the click events that are emited on MatchComponent inside of AdminTournamentComponent and not on FixtureLeagueComponent (because I want to change the behavior on others "TournamentComponents" but keep the FixtureComponent structure).

Is there any option to raise the unhandled events to "fixture-league" parent like:

```
<fixture-league (onDateClick)="doSomething()"></fixture-league>
```

If not, how can I avoid to create the same event emmiters on FixtureComponent but handle those events on AdminTournamentComponent?

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with multiple component levels, it is usually easier to move the event handling to dedicated service. Every component can then inject this service and either subscribe to the event or emit some value to it.

```
import { EventEmitter, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class MyEventService {

  private emitter = new EventEmitter<any>();

  public subscribe(callback: Function): void {
    this.emitter.subscribe(callback);
  }

  public emit(value: any = {}): void {
    this.emitter.emit(value);
  }

}
```

Then inject such a service and use it:

```
constructor(public eventService: MyEventService) {}

// emitting
<team [team]="match.local_team" (click)="evetService.emit('localClick')"></team>

// subscribing
ngOnInit() {
    this.eventService.subscribe(type => { console.log(type); });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand that that's the best solution for multiple levels. But what do you think in this case? Is better to do that or just create the same eventemitters on "FixtureComponent"?

PD: I want to create some diferent "Fixture" components, but I want to use them for admin purpose (maybe schedule the match or set the result), and user purpose (just see the information).

Comment: You could also create observable (`BehaviorSubject` usually) in the parent component and pass it down through property binding (square brackets), subscribe to it in parent and call `next` in child instead of `emit`. https://thinkster.io/tutorials/learn-rxjs-observables/using-behaviorsubject-for-values-that-change-over-time

Comment: I personally do not create duplicate event emitters because of this and use this feature only for 1 level communication. We have generic `EventsService` similar to this one, but with `Map` of emitters that is used for every other event based communication (not just between child/parent components).